# iPhone SDK Code Sign Error

Tags: iphone, code-signing-certificate

I am getting this error when I try to build for the device:

`Code Sign error: The identity 'iPhone Distribution' doesn't match any identity in any profile`

I am:

- Building for development, not release.
- Building for 3.1.2
- Running SDK 3.1.2

I have:

- Revoked and re-issued a valid certificate
- Created a new Ap ID and new associated provisioning profile with an explicit app name (com.mycompany.appname) and matched my Bundle Identifier to it (com.mycompany.appname).
- Selected the specific provisioning profile I created as my Code Signing Identity. (I uninstalled all my other CSI just in case.)  Just to reiterate: "iPhone Distribution" is not selected!

I should also stipulate that it won't even begin to build the code (even if there has been a clean build) because of this problem. So its not throwing this error when it tries to install to the device.

I have also read other StackOverflow threads about this issue, but they seem to be building for distribution and not development.

Any help would be much appreciated...

Comment: Double-check that you've not entered **iPhone Distribution** when you call the options on the main project file, as well if you call it from your target. And that the settings apply to the right build configuration.

Comment: Thanks SanHolo, I double checked and everything is OK on that front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried everything over the course of days and finally got it in my head to just make a new project and add back in all my source files.  It seemed like a long shot at the time, but it seems to have worked.  No idea why, but everything is running smoothly now.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've not installed 3.1.2 and not updated your SDK (or vice versa)? The minor version number *is* important, and mismatches can lead to this error.

Comment: I am updated to 3.1.2 on the SDK and my phone.  Same issue.

I should stipulate that it won't even begin to build the code (even if there has been a clean build) because of this problem.  So its not throwing this error when it tries to install to the device.

Answer (score 1):

Never really found a solution posted by somebody else so I'm sharing what I did to fix this problem below.

What I did was show the package contents of the '.xcodeproj', and then manually edit the 'project.pbxproj' file in there.

Look for a section called 'XCBuildConfiguration' and you should be able to see all the different configurations. I manually removed the ones related to code signing such as:

```
CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = dist.plist;
CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = "iPhone Distribution: xxxx yyyy";
"CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "iPhone Distribution: xxxx yyyy";
PROVISIONING_PROFILE = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
"PROVISIONING_PROFILE[sdk=iphoneos*]" = "zzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz";
```

So what was left was the following:

```
buildSettings = {
                ALWAYS_SEARCH_USER_PATHS = NO;
                COPY_PHASE_STRIP = NO;
                GCC_DYNAMIC_NO_PIC = NO;
                GCC_OPTIMIZATION_LEVEL = 0;
                GCC_PRECOMPILE_PREFIX_HEADER = YES;
                GCC_PREFIX_HEADER = xxx_Prefix.pch;
                INFOPLIST_FILE = "Info.plist";
                PRODUCT_NAME = xxx;
            };
```

You should remove for the other configurations as well, if there are any related to code signing